# SWT OLE for pdf: how to?

Tags: java, pdf, swt, ole

May be somebody have example of using SWT OLE for displaying pdf documents in Eclipse RTC Application.

Comment: Maybe this is related: [Any pdf reader library or way of opeing it in SWT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859618/any-pdf-reader-library-or-way-of-opeing-it-in-swt)

Comment: yes. you're right. but i would like to use one OLE Frame for all MS docs files and pdf. but maybe i'll try to use this variant. thanks.